# Коммуникационная проблема с Internet of Things устройством на базе TI CC1310

Tags: radio

Прошу помочь разобраться с коммуникационной проблемой. Разрабатываю устройства для Internet of Things на базе TI CC1310. Разработанное ПО проходит тесты на отладочных платах TI - соединение устанавливается, отладки обмениваются данными без потерь. При заливке ПО в разработанные платы соединение устанавливается, но данными платы не обмениваются. При этом, если подключать платы через SmartRF Studio от TI платы полностью работоспособны: RSSI и количество ошибок одинаковы с отладками. Проверял приемо-передачу посредством антенн на платах, скопированных с отладки, и посредством коаксиального кабеля - результат идентичен.